# Laravel: Join three tables get non existent row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this 3 tables
`users`,
`user_info`,
`attendances`

with sample data as follow:

**users table**

```
|id|username|    email        |     password    |
|1 |  user  | email@email.com |  hashedpassword |
|2 |  user2 | email2@email.com|  pw             |
```

**user_info table**

```
|id| user_id|    full_name    |       dob       |
|1 |  1     | Pedro Dela Cruz |  1991-09-10     |
|2 |  2     | John Doe        |  1987-05-25     |
```

**attendances table**

```
|id| user_id|    log_date     |       log_time  | status
|1 |  1     | 2018-08-17      |  06:36:36       |  in
|2 |  3     | 2018-08-17      |  06:53:25       |  in
|4 |  4     | 2018-08-17      |  06:36:36       |  in
|5 |  5     | 2018-08-17      |  06:53:25       |  in
```

What I need to get is the list of users who has no attendance for the current day
in this case user with id of `2` has no attendance for the current day.

I am using laravel and I used leftjoin to join the three tables but I am getting zero results.

this is how I query the table

```
    $absentees = DB::table('users as u')
         ->join('user_info as ud','ud.user_id','=','u.id')
         ->leftjoin('attendances as at','at.user_id','=','ud.user_id')
         ->select('ud.*','at.log_date','at.user_id','u.username')
         ->where('at.log_date','=', date('Y-m-d'))
         ->whereNull('u.deleted_at')
         ->whereNull('at.log_date')
         ->distinct()
         ->get();
```

thanks for the help

Comment: dis you post exact query ? you have missing bracket

Comment: conflict condition for `log_date`

Comment: @C2486, when I remove this line `->where('at.log_date','=', date('Y-m-d'))` I am getting results but only a few, not all of them.

Comment: Don't say 'today'. It has no meaning for people outside your time zone.

Comment: at.logdate should be part of the left join, not the where

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change the where clause into this

```
->where('at.log_date', date('Y-m-d'))
```

[Query Builder in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)